# Sort order of a Bitwise Enum

Tags: sorting, enums

Is there an intelligent way to identify the order of a Bitwise Enum?

Take this enum for example:

```
[System.FlagsAttribute()]
internal enum AnswersSort : int
{
    None = 0,
    Bounty = 1,
    MarkedAnswer = 2,
    MostVotes = 4 
}
```

If I combine these in different ways:

```
var result = AnswersSort.MarkedAnswer | AnswersSort.MostVotes | AnswersSort.Bounty;
result = AnswersSort.MostVotes | AnswersSort.Bounty | AnswersSort.MarkedAnswer;
```

Both results are 7 and the order is lost. Is there a way to do this without using an array or a list? Ideally I'm looking for a solution using an enum but I'm not sure how or if it's possible.

Comment: If you want to order the items, then you'll need an array or other list structure. This is a curious enough request that I'm wondering why you'd want to do such a thing.

Comment: My head is telling me use an array or list but my gut feeling is with a bunch of NAND, XOR, etc this can be done, eg 231,312. That's it, I'm not looking for a Bitwise combination I'll do a concatenation of the values! Obviously this is only intended for enums with less than 10 items (otherwise of course an array or list). Thanks Jim I think you have answered my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 10 values, you need 4 bits per item. You *could* treat the combination as a single 40-bit value, encoded with 4 bits per digit. So, given your two examples:

```
var result = AnswersSort.MarkedAnswer | AnswersSort.MostVotes | AnswersSort.Bounty;
result = AnswersSort.MostVotes | AnswersSort.Bounty | AnswersSort.MarkedAnswer;
```

The first would be encoded as

```
 0010 0100 0001
 ---- ---- ----
  |    |    - Bounty
  |    - MostVotes
  - MarkedAnswer
```

You could build that in a 64-bit integer:

```
long first = BuildValue(AnswersSort.MarkedAnswer, AnswersSort.MostVotes, AnswersSort.Bounty);

long BuildValue(params AnswersSort[] values)
{
    long result = 0;
    foreach (var val in values)
    {
        result = result << 4;
        result |= (int)val;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: This is a pretty amazing answer Jim. It's got bit shifting and all, I'll up vote now (at 1:30am) and repro tomorrow- thank you